# Getting faultcode from web service in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, web-services, nsurlrequest

whenever i try to request my server through NSUrlRequest, an xml code comes in -didRceivedata delegate method. when i print it some body fault come. How to do this?

Comment: Post your code and error what you get.

Comment: @Maul i am getting this error:
data received is = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
   <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
   <detail>
    <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">priyankad-ThinkPad-T410</ns2:hostname>
  
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: @Maul my code is:

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.5:9090/IphoneWebService/services/MyWebServiceTest"]];
    
    [request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *stringData = @"Hello";
    NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [conn start];
help?

Comment: @Maul i am not parsing any thing.. response coming is not what i want.. yes i am using SOAP api.. everytime i am receiving is this:
soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
   <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>

Comment: can you send me the request  which you have created and sent to server to get response?

Comment: @JekilPatel i have put my entire source code here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478728/error-in-getting-data-from-the-server/21479255?noredirect=1#comment32419037_21479255

Comment: @JekilPatel Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

With use of NSURLRequest, You may o/p as below
output code/somethng.

To get proper output ,you have to use - **NSXMLParserDelegate** and its delegate methods as below

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

I hope, you will get your answer...

Comment: parsing is ok.. but i am not getting the correct xml in response. In <body> i am not getting the correct result. This is what i am getting.:
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
   <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>

Comment: I am not sure. But there may a problem in web service. Plz check web service again.

Comment: can you send me the request  which you have created and sent to server to get response? Kindly check your request that you have created to get response.