# Error in getting data from the server

Tags: ios, iphone, soap

I am sending some data to my server using POST method. Code is as follows:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<myServer ip>"]];
[request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *stringData = @"Hello";
NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];
```

I am not receiving the correct data in  from the server.

The code for receiving is:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"didFinishLoading Called");
    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data received is = %@",newStr);
}
```

The response I receive is:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:ns1="xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</…;
        <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
        <detail>
```

Comment: can you post all your delegates methods of NSURLConnection?

Comment: Also, what's getting printed as newStr (if its getting printed that is)?

Comment: @Anil tis is what i am getting:

<soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
   <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
   <detail>

Comment: @Ilario there is nothing in any other delegate method. Can you tell me where i am wrong, i mean am the above output i.e <faultcode> in the body. It was supposed to come something different. Please help

Comment: check this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445945/no-action-header-was-found-error-message-while-using-soap-webservice

Comment: Did u ensure u are sending proper xml data to server, please check stringData

Comment: try to send :::::    [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];  No need to send ::: charset=utf-8

Comment: Are you really just sending `@"Hello";` ?

Comment: @Wain i have to send username and password, but for testing purpose i am just sending @"Hello"

Comment: @Swati same output continues!! do you what it means when it is written : <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring> .what exactly it means? do i have to edit my code with smthg?

Comment: just look into @Swati's given link you will understand how to get response from soap api

Answer (score 2):

You can't just test a SOAP service by sending an arbitrary string. All you are proving is that the URL is pointing to a server which is expecting to receive SOAP messages. You need to look at the server specification and create the appropriate SOAP payload to be sent. This should replace your current content in `stringData`.

Comment: ok i accept your point, can you tell me the code snippet that i have written above to POST data to server is correct?
Do i have to set any value for SOAP Action also like this:
[request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Actually first time i am dealing with server.Sorry for any childish question.

Comment: The code is generally correct. The headers and body content that you send are dependent on the server expectation. Generally you need to set `Content-Type` (XML or SOAP XML) and `Content-Length`.